# Is there a way to make my bash shell on mac enter a line break after each command?

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, format, line-breaks

I just started programming and find it hard to read through the lines of code to find where to start right after my command so it'd be nice to see line breaks before each prompt reappears.

Comment: I think it is more appropriate to ask this question in the Unix Stack exchange. http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Can you show what your problem is?  It doesn't make much sense.  The prompt appears after the last output from the previous command, and if the previous command is civilized, that last character will be a newline.

Comment: For the record: I agree with @AswinPJ that unix.stackexchange.com is a better place for it. I answered it because it's a quick answer, but I'm downvoting because I don't think it belongs on SO. Hope that's not against the rules.... would someone with more experience let me know if I shouldn't have done that?

Comment: @alexanderbird: If the question belongs elsewhere, but there's nothing wrong with it _per se_,  voting to close (selecting the appropriate reason) is the better course of action.

Comment: @mklement0, thanks - I've done that now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in, `~/.bash_profile`, set `PS1` to change the prompt. Start it with a newline, and then your terminal output will have a blank line between the last line of the command output and the prompt.

More details on how you can customize the prompt: [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-customize-the-command-prompt--net-20586)